# Visitor pattern with default for properties

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I would like to get folks' thoughts on the following approach, and perhaps even suggest better alternatives.

I have a weather simulation, and I want to be able to calculate specific properties as the simulation progresses. Suppose I have a Base Class `WeatherSim` from which different types of simulations derive. So I may have a `ConstantTemperatureWeatherSim` or `ConstantPressureWeatherSim`, etc..

In the case of `ConstantTemperatureWeatherSim` I may be interested in how the average barometric pressure changes with time (iterations in the actual simulation), and so on. I may also run the same simulations, where I want to monitor other properties, such as average velocity field vector, or some arbitrary quantity which I desire.

The thing is, I need to calculate the properties in the most efficient way possible, since these simulations are **very** computationally expensive. This means that while I can have a vector of property calculating functions, like this:

```cpp
class ConstTempWeatherSim {
    std::vector<std::function<double(Model&)>> properties;

    void Iterate() {
     // Perform calculations...

     // Calculate properties
     for(auto& property : properties)
          property(model);
}
```

This approach is very inefficient. For the case of say, average pressure, I can loop though *all* elements in the model and get the pressure property on every iteration. A much more effective approach is to keep a running average.

The thing is, I don't want to pollute my class with every possible calculable quantity (and frankly I can't even if I wanted to, since I don't know what weird property a user may want to calculate).

My solution to this problem was to use somewhat of a visitor pattern. My `WeatherSim` is a `Visitable` object, and the property I want to calculate is my `Visitor`. I store a vector of `Visitors` in my `WeatherSim` and each iteration I call the `Visitors` to do their thing. Each visitor will accept a reference to `WeatherSim` and so they can store their running average internally.

In my mind that is a good way of solving this issue, except there are two other things I need to resolve, which is why I'm here.

1. Some properties are needed to perform calculations in a specific simulation. So for example, I may need to use pressure in my `ConstantTempWeatherSim` as part of the algorithm. Should I just keep a running average of the required property separately from my `Visitors` and use those to augment the properties already computed by the `WeatherSim`? Or should I have a private vector of `PropertyVisitors` that I use for the necessary properties and have the user add anything else they need to a separate queue? Is there some other way?
2. After each iteration, `WeatherSim` calls Observers to log the desired information. What's the best way of getting the data from the `PropertyVisitors` to the `Observer`? I don't think it would be wise to pass in a vector of references to the `PropertyVisitors` themselves to the `Observers`. I was thinking that in my `SimEvent` class, which contains information on the event, I could get the values  from all the `PropertyVisitors` and store them in a vector in `SimEvent`. Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Perhaps the visitor pattern isn't the best approach to this. I would appreciate thoughts on how to approach this problem.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: It is not clear to me what a `Model` is? or how a `WeatherSim` relates to the "properties". I think an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help. Of course any MCVE is going to vastly oversimplify things but I think it would at least help understand the roles of the different objects you mentioned and how they relate to each other.

Comment: Your example seems to suggest that a "property" is calculated as a result of the calculations done by the `WeatherSim` for a particular iteration. But the `WeatherSim` may also use some properties as part of the calculations. Is that using properties from a previous iteration? Or is there some kind of dependency graph where you can't calculate something else until you have calculated the pressure property.

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. A model is simply a representation of a volume, say a 30 cubic mile region of the mid-Atlantic. The `WeatherSim` operates on that volume. So the idea of a property is quite simple - there is no dependency graph and all properties are simply representing a particular state of the `Model`. So for example, if I wanted a `ConstantTemperature` Sim, then it would monitor the temperature each iteration and adjust (say the volume) of the box to maintain that temperature.

Comment: So in a `ConstantTemperature` case, I may want to see how the average pressure fluctuates in a simulation at constant temperature. And that's the scenario I'm describing.

Answer (score 0):

The Visitor pattern feels like a slightly strange fit here. Normally with the visitor pattern, the visitor needs to be aware of all the different possible visitable types. This is how it achieves double-dispatch on type of visitor and type of visitable. It is suitable if the different visitable types are reasonably static but you might need to add new visitors in the future. In your case this means the properties need to be aware of all different types of `WeatherSim` which doesn't sound quite right to me. I would not have expected that kind of coupling.

But to answer your specific questions based on my limited understanding:

1. I would suggest having only one list of properties but some properties might need to be registered as being one of the special properties for a particular simulation. The register of special properties just stores a reference to the property. The user can then choose, for example, which property they want to register as being the special "Pressure" property. Perhaps the special `Pressure` property would need to conform to some "Pressure" interface/template to be registered.
2. There are typically two ways to run Observers push or pull. You either push a set of data to all Observers which is what I think you are suggesting by copying values into the `SimEvent`. Or you just tell the Observers that something has changed and it is the responsibility of the Observers to pull information they require from the simulation. I think both are valid ways of running things and which way to go will depend on your particular requirements. The push model can be inefficient because you have to push all the data even if a particular Observer might not be interested in some of it. The pull model can be inefficient because communication is done in two steps and the Observer may have to find out what data has changed exactly itself. The pull model introduces more coupling between the Observers and the simulation. In the push model you might have to change the set of data that is pushed every time an Observer needs something new.